# Determining the capacitance of a system with a non-homogenous dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance

In an experiment we were given non-homogenous dielectric substances described by functions of coordinate. How can capacitance be determined from this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following equations coming from electrostatic:

$$\nabla\cdot(\epsilon({\bf x}){\bf E})=\rho({\bf x})$$

$${\bf E}=-\nabla\phi$$

with the proper boundary conditions. Then, with the definition of capacitance you will get the result. This is not often feasible analytically and will depend on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (flawed) method on doing it--which works for many cases Otherwise @Jon's method is the way to go.

Break it into infinitesimal thin rods so that you get $\infty$ parallel capacitors of area $\rm dA$. Usually one of the directions will be homogenous, so you can write $\rm dA=z\rm dy$. Otherwise, $\rm dA=dy\cdot dz$

Break each rod into infinitesimal chunks and get $\infty$ series capacitors per slice of thickness $\rm dx$.

For each rod, find the infinitesimal reciprocal of capacitance $\rm d(\frac1C_{chunk})$ (in terms of $(x,y,z)$ Integrate $\int \rm d(\frac1C_{chunk})=\frac1{dC_{rod}}$

Now integrate $\int \rm dC_{rod}=C_{eq}$

The issue here is, when you break them into a set of series capacitors, you use the capacitors-in-series formula. This assumes that charge distribution on each capacitor in series is the same--which is wrong in this case. We can't apply charge conservation on a rod here, as charge can enter and leave from various spots.

Usually, a sufficently symmetric case works.